# Shapeless HList Polymorphic Function with a Tuple and Function

Tags: scala, shapeless

With the following code snippet I cannot figure out why the final value `result` is of type `Any`:

```
object reporter extends Poly1 {
  implicit def wrap[T, F <% (Function1[String, T], Nat)] = at[F] { fn =>
    val f = fn._1
    val n = fn._2
    println(s"Running ${n}")
    f.asInstanceOf[Function[String, T]]
  }
}

val stringToInt = ((s: String) => s.toInt) :: HNil
val indexed = stringToInt zipWithIndex
val reported = indexed map reporter

// this is an `Any`, unfortunately
val result = reported.head("1")
```

The types appear correct before the `map`, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where it's losing the type.

Note: this is running against Shapeless 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't want to find yourself writing `Nat` when using Shapeless except as an upper-bound constraint on a type parameter (or in some particular cases where you want to accept a literal integer value as a parameter and have it be available at the type level, but that's not relevant here).

In your case the view bound will get desugared to an implicit parameter of type `F => (String => T, Nat)`, and the Scala compiler won't properly infer the `T`. If I were less tired of thinking about Scala at the moment I could try to figure out why, but I'm not sure it matters much, since you don't want or need to be in this situation to start with—instead you can just add an `N <: Nat` type parameter and skip the view bound entirely:

```
import shapeless._

object reporter extends Poly1 {
  implicit def wrap[T, N <: Nat]: Case.Aux[(String => T, N), String => T] =
    at[(String => T, N)] { fn =>
      val f = fn._1
      val n = fn._2
      println(s"Running ${n}")
      f
    }
  }

val stringToInt = ((s: String) => s.toInt) :: HNil
val indexed = stringToInt zipWithIndex
val reported = indexed map reporter

val result = reported.head("1")
```

This will work as expected and `result` will be statically typed as an `Int`.

Comment: You're a wizard. One more question I just realized I missed. How do I get the correct implicit to get `n.toInt` to work?

Comment: @jsw What I'd suggest is adding a `(implicit ti: ops.nat.ToInt[N])` implicit parameter list to `wrap` and then just using `ti()` to get the value (instead of working with the `Nat` value).

Comment: One quibble ... using plain `Nat` as a method argument type makes sense where you expect it to be the target of an implicit conversion from an `Int` literal to a `Nat`. See [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala#L89) for example.

Comment: @MilesSabin I already quibbled that (in my first parenthetical)! :)

Comment: @TravisBrown (so you did :-) )